# how to sort an array of objects by the parents of the objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model objects:

```
Participants.rb

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :board

Users.rb

has_many :participants

Boards.rb

has_many :participants
```

I want to sort the following array by the name of the users when I get the information from the database; i.e. something like:

```
participants = get_current_board.participants.where(:role => "Participant").order(participants.user.name)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
 participants.sort {|x,y| x.user.name <=> y.user.name }
```

Comment: This would sort in Ruby, not the in the database.

Comment: Its from Ruby. I misread the requirement. But i think it would be better if its done on ruby then DB.

Comment: Databases are good at sorting. If the sorting is trivial, and the query deals with a lot of data, I'd rather have the database do it.

Comment: A matter of preference ... Surely I would not do in DB unless its a simple sort, on fields of same table, without any overhead ...

Comment: Like I said, if it's *trivial*. Sorting in Ruby can be very slow if you're dealing with a lot of data, beware of that.

Comment: I agreed to your point. Also, yup can be slow if the data is hugh.

Comment: In my case I could not get the database sort to work so used the above to sort the data after its returned from the database.

Answer (score 1):

To let your database to the sorting:

```
participants = get_current_board.participants.where(:role => "Participant").joins(:user).order(:users => :name)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and I got this error TypeError (can't convert Hash into String):
any ideas?

Comment: What is "role" in your model, a string field in user?

Comment: role is a string field in participants

Answer (score 0):

participants = get_current_board.participants.includes(:user).where(:role => "Participant").order(:users=>:name)

You are use this with eager loading

Comment: This did not produce any errors. However it did not seem to affect the order of the participants. It still put them in order of the participants id and not the users name. Any ideas?